# difference between toggle button and switch

Tags: button, sapui5, user-experience, sap-fiori

What is the difference between a toggle button and switch? As they provide same feature, what is the specific use case to use a toggle button or a switch?

Toggle button:

[image: Toggle Button]

Switch:

[image: Switch]

Comment: This question isn't related to programming. Better ask at https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a User Experience question than just Coding. Here is my answer:

The description of the control says it:

**Toggle** is a button : [sap.m.ToggleButton](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ToggleButton/overview)

whereas

**switch** is a user input.
[sap.m.Switch](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Switch/preview)

However, the main difference lies in the User Experience and usage.

Here is what the Fiori Guideline says: [When to use Switch](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/switch/#usage)

> - You need to emphasize the On/Off characteristic within a dialog.
> - You need to clearly show the mode or state that a setting is in.
> - You need a toggle switch for binary settings when changes become effective   immediately after the user changes them. For example, if
>     the user    needs to set data transmission or accept/reject business
>     objects.

vs

[Behavior of Buttons](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/button/#toggle-button)

To summarize, I can say: 
Switch primarily represents a state(a physical state like a fan "On' or "Off")
and the text should not be too big.

whereas, a button is an action mostly a verb which user performs and this can be a longer text like "Activate

You can read a little more on the difference based on UX with an example: 
[Difference between switch and toggle](https://www.designmap.com/the-difference-between-a-light-switch-and-a-toggle-in-ux/)