# How to create an accessible 2-state switch?

Tags: html, wai-aria

There are many ways to create an accessible 2-state switch.(looks like a buton,click to change state)

A "switch": created by checkbox [inclusive-considerations-when-restyling-form-controls](https://24ways.org/2018/inclusive-considerations-when-restyling-form-controls/)

```html
<input type="checkbox" role="switch" checked/>
```

A "toggle button" created by checkbox

```html
<input type="checkbox" role="button" aria-pressed="true"/>
```

A "switch": created by button [ant design](https://ant-design-vue.gitee.io/components/switch-cn/)

```html
<button role="switch" aria-checked="true"></button>
```

A "switch" created by radio [Switch Component: Radio Buttons](https://scottaohara.github.io/a11y_styled_form_controls/src/radio-button--switch/)

There are the following advantages and disadvantages:

- switch component looked more like button than checkbox
- values in checkboxs always be transfered to Array data
- button always be used to control action, not a data container
- ChromeVox can't read `switch` role.
- checkbox's `:checked` state can be controled with css
- No need to script aria if use checkbox's attribute `checked`
- Radio's keys are `↑↓←→`, checkbox's keys are `space|return|enter`

So which is the best?

Further more, how to create a accessible 3-state(or more) switch?

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#switch

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#button

[difference between toggle button and switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525778/difference-between-toggle-button-and-switch)